# Web api route wint action require names for multiple get method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have an asp.net mvc controller named product.

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("product");
    }
}
```

And my route is like this.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultRoute", 
     "api/{controller}/{id}", 
      new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

I can access the product Get method like this url: `localhost:2541/api/product`

And I need some estra get methots.

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("product");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Hello()
    {
        return Ok("Hello from product");
    }
}
```

And I set new route.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("ActionsRoute", 
    "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

But I can not access to `localhost:2541/api/product`

Error:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request: Get

Answer (score 0):

That is because by including `{action}` route parameter it is now required to include the name of the action in the request other wise it will not know which action to select.  like

```
localhost:2541/api/product/Get
```

If the root is still desired then include default when mapping route.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("ActionsRoute", 
    "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    new { action = "Get", id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

With that done, the calls below will map as followed

```
GET localhost:2541/api/product        --> ProductController.Get
GET localhost:2541/api/product/Get    --> ProductController.Get
GET localhost:2541/api/product/Hello  --> ProductController.Hello
```